# How would you say "Influenced Thinking" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

After years of contemplation on imposter syndrome, I have decided to finally write my thoughts, experiments, and ideas about the field that I work in on a blog.

Google Translate offers the phrase "*motus cogitandi*" as the translation for the words "Influenced Thinking", but I am hesitant to trust it as I have no prior knowledge of Latin. I would appreciate knowing the grammatically correct translation of the phrase "Influenced Thinking" in Latin.

Edit: Here, the term *influenced thinking* refers to the notion that thinking about things or people is of the highest form of influence/flattery/respect. It is, in my opinion, to think about things that do not interest you for prolonged periods of time - but if something piques your curiosity, you'll certainly have something to think about. Additionally, the blog is written with the mindset that what I plan to write is a product of the influences that have affected my thinking. It *may* influence others, but that is not the objective. Lastly, a noun would be a better fit than a verb here.

Comment: People can take a guess, but to save us wasted efforts, can you edit your question so that you provide a meaning and some additional context as to what "influenced thinking" surrounding this term?

Comment: @cmw, I have added the context in my post, thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Having read your edited question and the context that you've provided, I'm not at all sure why the phrase you're asking for is 'influenced thinking' (that is, thinking that is influenced by something/someone) rather than 'influencing thinking' (that is, thinking that influences something/someone).

Comment: @cnread - The reason is that what I plan to write is a product of the influences that have affected my thinking. It *may* influence others, but that is not the objective.

Comment: Are you looking for a verb (to think in a way that's influenced), or a noun (a method or pattern of thinking that has been influenced)?

Comment: @Draconis - I think a noun would be a better fit!

Comment: Fair enough, but that isn't what you say in the edited portion of your question. Please update the question so that it *accurately* describes what you're after. Otherwise, it's very difficult to offer meaningful help.